# Excel - Conditional Formatting till the last column

Tags: excel

I would like to highlight cells from 2nd cell to the last cell that has data in a given row based on the value in 2nd column. I was able to highlight the entire row or hardcode the last column name. But the last data column keeps changing as the user adds new data in the last columns(empty cells may be there in between - even these empty cells should get highlighted).
Could somebody please guide me on how to highlight all the cells till the last column that has data using conditional formatting.
Thanks,
Sri.

EDIT: 
@ChetterHummin, Infact in one sheet there are around 500 accounts with various account levels. Top most parent will be present in the 2nd column, its child accounts will be in 3rd col and their child accounts will be in 4 column etc. Totally accounts spread over 10 levels. Leaf accounts will be there in the 11th column. I need to highlight rows in various colors based on account level, i.e in which column the account is present. if the accounts is present in 2nd column i.e. the cell value of 2nd column is not empty, I need to highlight all the cells(till the last data cell) in that row in one color. And if 3rd column is not empty i need to highlight the cells in that row till the last data col in some other color. -Hope this gives a better picture of what i wanted to do.

Comment: Could you post some examples of values? That might clarify the question a bit

Answer (score -1):

You need to add multiple rules based on the last cell and give the rule based on the lowest level the topmost priority and so on as you can see from my example.

[image: Conditional formatting]

Edit: I do realize now that you wanted to color only until last cell that has data. I'll leave it here as an FYI or inspiration for other answers. I do not see, at the moment, how to achieve what you are trying to achieve.